# LEGB scope of variables in python

Tags: python

Can any one please explain why the output of below code is 0,1,2,3,4?

```
fun=[]
for i in range(5):
    def f(i=i):
        #i=10
        print(i)
    fun.append(f)
#print(fun,i)
for f in fun:
    f()
```

what is happening if giving default value(i=i)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is a variable scope issue that can easily be avoided by following general best practices and not giving variables the same name.

In the first for loop you are creating a bunch of functions and appending them to a list. In the second for loop you call each one of those functions from the list and it executes. In the definition of function `f` you give the parameter `i` the default value of `i`. The local function parameter `i` (the first one) if assigned the value of the global variable `i` which is incremented with every loop iteration. Inside the function `f` the print statement prints the local variable `i` (because of variable scope rules). The result of this first for loop is a list of 5 functions that print the local parameter `i`, but for each one the local parameter `i` has been given a different default value.

This code can be more clearly written as:

```
function_list = []
for index in range(5):
    def print_func(val=index):
        print(val)
    function_list.append(print_func)

for func in function_list:
    func()
```

This eliminates all conflicting variable and function names and makes the code more readable and understandable.

You can read http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html for more on variable scope.